# spring boot sample hateoas not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to run the hateoas spring boot example located at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-hateoas (I'm trying to run Version 1.2.6.RELEASE).

When accessing the customers service provided by the example I get a MarshalException:

> Could not marshal [Resources { content:
>   [sample.domain.Customer@72c01d5a, sample.domain.Customer@5ef1ebf9,
>   sample.domain.Customer@237de11a], links:
>   [http://localhost:8080/customers;rel="self"] }]: null; nested
>   exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException - with linked exception:
>   [com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class sample.domain.Customer
>   nor any of its super class is known to this context.
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class sample.domain.Customer nor any of
>   its super class is known to this context.]

This is caused by the following code:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
HttpEntity<Resources<Customer>> showCustomers() {
    Resources<Customer> resources = new Resources<Customer>(this.repository.findAll());
    resources.add(this.entityLinks.linkToCollectionResource(Customer.class));
    return new ResponseEntity<Resources<Customer>>(resources, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

While I could probably implement my own

```
public class CustomerResources extends Resources<Customer> {
```

I'd like to avoid this if at all possible.

Also if it has to be like this I'm confused why it's not like this in the example. Am I missing something? How can I get the sample to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do really want to send XML?

Comment: I would be find with not sending XML but I'd really like the URLs to work by default from a browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample is intended to work with JSON and will serve JSON by default. I guess you're sending a request with an `Accept` header that requests `application/xml`. Try removing the header, or requesting `application/json` instead.

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot. Is there a way to disable the default xml output or switch to default json so that visiting the URLs with a browser shows the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

While working with HATEOAS, Exception: **javax.xml.bind.MarshalException** occurs when you do not add correct producer type with URI.

Whenever you use HATEOAS in Spring boot, you need to add produces type as **application/hal+json**.

Example: 
@PostMapping(value="/yourUri",**produces = "application/hal+json"**)

This worked for me!